# Tkinter text widget : pressing <Return> key goes to line

Tags: python, tkinter, return

I'm trying to make a chat with tkinter using a widget text with the Enter key binded like this :

```
self.msg.bind('<Return>', self.chatReturn)

def chatReturn(self, evt):          
      self.chat.config(state = NORMAL)
      self.chat.insert(END, self.msg.get(1.0, END))
      self.chat.config(state = DISABLED)
      self.msg.delete(1.0, END)
```

But after chatReturn() being called, the "Return" key makes the cursor go to the second line...

Can I disable the normal state of the "Return" key from going to the next line ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Returning the string `break` prevent Tkinter from propagating event to other handlers.

```
def chatReturn(self, evt):          
    self.chat.config(state = NORMAL)
    self.chat.insert(END, self.msg.get(1.0, END))
    self.chat.config(state = DISABLED)
    self.msg.delete(1.0, END)
    return 'break' # <---------
```